# Firestore query with logical OR filter requires multiple indexes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am running the following `Firestore` query:

```
db
  .collection("collectionId")   
  .whereFilter(
    Filter.orFilter([
      Filter.whereField("x", isEqualTo: "a"), 
      Filter.whereField("y", isEqualTo: "a")
    ]))
  .order(by: "dateAdded", descending: true)
  .limit(to: 20)
  .getDocuments
```

The error that prints out is that the query requires multiple indexes. When I click the provided link to create the index I get redirected to a blank page, so I tried manually entering a composite index.

1. Collection Id: "collectionId"
2. Fields to Index: ["x", Ascending], ["y", Ascending], ["dateAdded", Descending]
3. Query Scope: Collection

My issue is that I am still receiving the same error. Any guidance or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create two different indexes, not a composite index.  Imagine if you were doing two queries, one with a filter on x and another with a filter on y (not both at the same time).  They would each require different indexes.  That's essentially what Firestore is doing for you: both queries, then removing the duplicates between them.  So you will need one index for x and dateAdded, then another for y and dateAdded.

Comment: thank you. i added the two indexes as outlined, but i actually still seem to receive the same error after the indexes have been built and i re-run the query. any other thoughts?

Comment: I don't know, but the link going to an blank page sounds like a bug that you could report to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: reported it and found a workaround. answer is still correct.